# Using new and channel in go

Tags: go

I found the code snippet below on a tech talk, I am a little bit confused about one thing.

Should `table <- new(Ball)` be placed before `go player("ping", table)`?
And why do we even need `table <- new(Ball)`? I think `table := make(chan *Ball)` already creates the channel. 
Has this something to do with deadlocks?

```
type Ball struct { hits int }

fun main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)
    table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
    time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
    <-table // game over; grab the ball
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball)
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Contrary to other languages you almost never need to construct objects with `new` in Go. Most things are either constructed directly (via) a literal or via `make`.

Comment: I never use the `new` keyword in my code. It feels too "Java"-ish... ew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<-` operator is what places something in the channel, or takes it out. The side it's on shows you if it's being placed in, or taken out. Because the channel doesn't have a size it cannot actually "hold" and item, it makes the `go` funcs block until there is something put in the channel. Both sides (insert and remove) block on a channel with no size, so if you try to insert something when there is no receiver, it blocks until there is one. In this specific code, the `player` func then removes it `<- table` and places it back in `table <-`.

As to your question regarding moving `table <- new(Ball)`. If you try to send the ball without a receiver, main blocks waiting for something to take the ball. A channel without a size is more like "handing" off objects because there is no storage involved. If, instead, it was created with a buffer size e.g. `table := make(chan *Ball, 1)`, then it only blocks (the same as before) when it already has 1 item in it. So if you created it with a buffer of one, but tried to place 2 balls in it before the `go` funcs, it would deadlock same as before.

https://play.golang.org/p/zrN0D8IYnn

Comment: I wonder why there is deadlock when I remove   table <-new(Ball) ?  Also why when I put table<-new (Ball) before go player function, it does not work? Thanks

Comment: Because the ball is taken from the table at the end of main. If there is no ball, main will block and wait for one.... forever. EDIT: Oh shoot, I forgot to add something.

Comment: thank you. i still don't understand why when I put table<-new (Ball) before go player function, it does not work?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to organize my thoughts.